# Does the Kalika Purana identify itself as "Srimad Bhagavatam"?

Tags: bhagavata-purana, devi-bhagavata-purana

The identity of which text being the real "Srimad Bhagavatam" has often (unfortunately) been a source of tension between Vaishnavas and Shaktas. Vaishnavas claim that the Bhagavata Purana dedicated to Vishnu/Krishna, is the real "Srimad Bhagavatam" whereas the Shaktas claim that the real "Srimad Bhagavatam" is none other than the Devi Bhagavata Purana.

However, it seems that the Bhagavata Purana and the Devi-Bhagavata Purana aren't the only texts to claim themselves to be the real "Srimad Bhagavatam".

Quoting from the "[**Puranic Records On Hindu Rites And Customs
by R C Hazra**](https://archive.org/download/PuranicRecordsOnHinduRitesAndCustoms/Puranic%20Records%20On%20Hindu%20Rites%20And%20Customs.pdf)":

> 6. THE BHAGAVATA-PURANA.
>
> The Bhagavata is the most popular of the extant Puranas. It 
>   belongs to the Bhagavatas and is divided into 12 Skandhas or books 
>   dealing with cosmogony, genealogies, myths, legends etc. It also 
>   contains a few chapters on Smrti-matter, viz., Ill, 30 on the results 
>   of actions (Karma-vipaka) , VII, 11-13 and XI, 17-18 on the duties 
>   of the castes and Asramas, and VII, 14-15 on funeral sacrifices and 
>   holy places.
>
> It has been held by the Saktas that the Bhagavata is not a 
>   Mahapurana as the Vaisnavas claim. But these Saktas themselves 
>   are not unanimous about the indentity of the ‘Bhagavata’ named in 
>   the lists of the eighteen Mahapuranas. **Some of them say that it is 
>   the Kalika-Purana which, on account of its treatment of the birth 
>   and exploits of Bhagavati, is called ‘Bhagavata’**. Some, again, claim 
>   that it is the Devibhagavata. It is, therefore, necessary to see which 
>   one is the real Mahapurana.

My questions are:

• Does the Kalika-Purana explicitly state itself to be the "Srimad Bhagavatam"?

• Does the Kalika-Purana make any mention the other two contending Puranas i.e. the Bhagavata Purana and the Devi-Bhagavata Purana (since the Devi-Bhagavata Purana mentions the Bhagavata Purana dedicated to Krishna/Vishnu as an Upapurana as well as the Kalika Purana)

Comment: next what? ganapati bhagavata, yama bhagavata,rudra bhagavata,saura bhagavata? too many claims for one title 'bhagavata'

Comment: @LogTran Anything relating to Bhagavan or Bhagavati can be termed as Bhagavata.So no problem in that!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**NO**, as per my knowledge, **it does not call itself "Bhagavata Purana"** but it is considered the implication from Kalika Purana which is focused on Bhagavati. What Kalika Purana declares, is that it is **the supreme scripture.** In one translation on archive (https://archive.org/details/KalikaPuranamVol.1AcharyaMrityunjayTripathi/page/n31/mode/2up) you can see Markandeya says:

> आप सभी मुनिगण मेरे द्वारा कथित अत्यंत गोपनीय से भी गोपनीय, पवित्र, शुभकर्ता, सम्यक, ज्ञान प्रदान करने तथा कामना की पूर्ति करने वाले, **श्रेष्ठ, इस कलिका पुराण** को सभी सुने
>
> Which basically translates to -- *All you munis, listen to this
> extremely hidden, sacred, auspicious, complete/correct, knowledge
> giving and wish fulfilling, **supreme**, Kalika Purana.*

Here is another abridged version of the Purana in Hindi - https://archive.org/details/HindiBookKalikaPuran/page/n3/mode/2up . It also says that this scripture is supreme:

> यह  लिखा  हुआ  **उत्तम  पुराण**  ... यह  **परम  तंत्र**  है  ... **इससे  अधिक  अन्य  कुछ   भी  नहीं  है**
>
> Which means that *this is the **best purana** ... the **supreme
> tantra** ... there is **nothing more** other than this* (Kalika
> Purana).

The reference to Bhagavata is not inside the purana itself but people like **Hemadri in Chaturvarga Chintamani called it the Bhagavata.** There is also another verse in Skanda Purana, Kedara Khanda 1. which hints on this subject:

> अष्टादशपुराणेषु दशभिर्गीयते शिवः। चतुर्भिर्भगवान् ब्रह्मा **द्वाभ्यां देवी** तथा हरिः॥
> ‘अठारह पुराणों में दस में शिव-स्तुति है, चार में ब्रह्मा की और **दो में देवी** तथा हरि की है।’
>
> Which means -- *Out of the 18 Mahapuranas there are 10 of Shiva, 4 of Brahma, **2 of Devi** and Vishnu each.*

So the interpretation is

- Kalika Purana is called the **supreme scripture**
- **It is focused on Bhagavati**
- It could be a Mahapurana mentioned in Skanda Purana of **Shivite sect**

Which could mean that it is the Bhagavata. But again, there is no explicit reference to itself as "Bhagavata Purana".

Comment: Well this is no suprise most hindu scriptures claim to be the supreme scripture.

Comment: You can Tell reference of mayavadi in kalika purana